# ZTE Valet device not showing up in Android Device Chooser (Windows 8.1)

Tags: android, usb, adb, windows-8.1

I am developing an android app for a ZTE Valet (Android version: 4.1.1) on windows 8.1 using the Eclipse IDE for Android Developers (Juno).

After selecting debug,  the Android Device Chooser pops up with no devices shown in the "Choose a running Android Device". In the manifest, I set the min API level set to 14, which is also shown in the Android Device Chooser, i.e. "Select a device with min API level 14."

I have already turned on USB debugging on in the developer option on the phone.

Window 8.1's device manager shows Z665C (the phone's model) under portable devices and also Android under Unknown devices. To try and correct the unknown device, I downloaded the ZTE USB driver from http://support.zte.com.cn/support/news/NewsDetail.aspx?newsId=1000442.  However, the driver is only for 32/64 bit windows 7 and vista.

I am able to see the SD card and the internal memory through windows explorer.

I am a lost at what to do next.  Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work.  After connecting the USB cable, a popup will appear in the upper right hand corner of the computer screen, i.e. "Tap to choose what happens with the disc".

Select Run AutoRun.exe and complete the process of installing the USB driver.  Once the program is finished installing the USB driver, restart the computer.

Comment: Add that as an answer so your question doesn't show as unanswered.

Comment: I have no autorun.exe option.  Any other ideas?  I pretty much went through the same steps, installed that file in your link and see the device in device manager same as you.. but ADB doesn't recognize it.

Comment: eselk: did the "Tap to choose what happens with the disc" show up in the right hand corner?